# Custom Delimiter in SQL Server Management Studio does not work

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, delimiter

I'm trying to change my delimiter to a pipe:

[image]

I have restarted SQL Server Management Studio. However, I keep having the csv file with the previous delimiter.

[image]

Is it necessary to do something else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting custom delimiter for Results to Text option. But, you are trying to save results in the Results to Grid option.

If you are having Results to Text option (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), you will get the result properly. You can copy and save the result accordingly.

[image]

**update**:

- **To turn off rowcount**

```sql
SET NOROWCOUNT ON -- Add this setting before SELECT query
SELECT ...
```

Or in the

> Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced > check SET NOROWCOUNT

- **To turn off completion time**

> Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced. Uncheck the
> Show Completion Time checkbox

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is is possible to indicate that I just need the information from the table. Because I'm going to be dealing whit very large files and it is going to be difficult to open them in a text editor to delete the information regarding the row count and the completion time.

Comment: just amazing. I've been struggling with getting pipe separated for a couple of days. Thanks a lot!!